# Not all arguments converted during string formatting (Proving Collatz Conjecture)

Tags: python, python-2.7, type-conversion, collatz

When I run the code below I get an error. I have looked here on StackOverflow, but I ended up not solving my problem.

```
print "insert value"
value = raw_input ()

flag = False
i = 0

while flag:
    if value == 1:
        flag = True
    elif value % 2 == 0:
        value = value / 2
    else:
        value = value * 3
        value = value + 1
    i = i + 1

print "After", i, "attempts the conjecture has been demonstrated"
```

I get an error in the `elif` logical test `value% 2 == 0` which says

`not all arguments converted during string formatting`

I think the problem is in the variable type but I tried the `input` function and forcing the `int` type, `value = int (input (....))`, but that also didn't work.

Comment: What exactly is value % 2 == 0: supposed to be doing?

Comment: it's supposed to check if value is even

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IDLE this worked for me

```
value = int(raw_input ())
```

converting raw input into integer

```
while True:
    if value == 1:
        break
    elif value % 2 == 0:
        value = value / 2
    else:
        value = value * 3
        value = value + 1
    i = i + 1
```

a bit simpler way to do while without having arbitrary flag

Comment: Im a student and it worked thanks I will accepted as soon as I can (3mins)

Answer (score 2):

iScrE4m has shown how to fix your program, but I'll explain why you got that

`TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

error message.

When the Python interpreter sees `%` after a string it interprets the `%` as the [string interpolation operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting), which is used to convert data and insert it into a string.

For example

```
a = 2
b = 3
print "%d + %d = %d" % (a, b, a + b)
```

**output**

```
2 + 3 = 5
```

In your code, `value` is a string so the interpreter tries to do string interpolation on `value % 2` but then it sees that `value` isn't a valid format string to format the data `2`, so it gives you that `TypeError`.

In modern code use of `%`-style string formatting is discouraged and the [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method is preferred. The equivalent to the above example is:

```
print "{0} + {1} = {2}".format(a, b, a + b)
```

In Python 2.7 and later you can omit the field numbers:

```
print "{} + {} = {}".format(a, b, a + b)
```

---

I have a few more comments on your code.

When calling a function in Python it's conventional to *not* put a space after the function name.

There's no need to use `print` to print a prompt before calling `raw_input`: you can (and should) supply the prompt as an argument to `raw_input`.

When performing integer division you should use the integer division operator `//`. A single slash works ok in Python 2, but in Python 3 it won't behave as expected here because it will perform a floating-point division. Eg, `10 / 2` will result in `5.0`.

When you need to perform a single operation on a variable and save the result of that operation back to the same variable you can use an augmented assignment operator. Eg,
instead of `i = i + 1` you can write `i += 1`;
instead of `value = value // 2` you can write `value //= 2`.

Also, instead of

```
value = value * 3
value = value + 1
```

you *could* do

```
value *= 3
value += 1
```

However, when performing multiple operations on a variable it's a little more compact and efficient to do them on one line. So it would be more usual to do:

```
value = value * 3 + 1
```

Putting it all together, here's a re-worked version of your code.

```
value = int(raw_input("Enter value: "))
i = 0
while True:
    if value == 1:
        break
    elif value % 2 == 0:
        value //= 2
    else:
        value = value * 3 + 1
    i += 1    

print "After {} attempts the conjecture has been demonstrated.".format(i)
```